# What are some top reasons to upgrade to .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net

What are some top reasons to upgrade to .NET 4.0?

Comment: This top ten list isn't funny at all.

Comment: Haven't we been through this a couple of times already ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the compelling reason to upgrade to Visual Studio 2010 from VS2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885955/whats-the-compelling-reason-to-upgrade-to-visual-studio-2010-from-vs2008)

Comment: So you can donate some more money to Microsoft.

Comment: @Brian: not really a duplicate, that (at summary anyway) doesn't really covert the framework changes.

Answer (score 7):

[What's new in .NET 4?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx)

The big ones are probably MEF, Parallel tasks and MVC 2.  But it also has dynamic support, big integer support, covariance, contravariance and so on and so on.  Take a look.

Comment: +1 for including the same link as me!

Comment: MVC 2 can be used in projects targeting .NET 3.5, but you need to [download it separately](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/11/asp-net-mvc-2-released.aspx). However, you won't be able to take advantage of the new HTML-encoding expression that was introduced as part of ASP.NET 4.

Answer (score 4):

[Improved support for parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The Parellel Library.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Entity Framework 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/) which supports both Model & Code First Approachs,T4 templates (custom code generations), and a better API for advanced data access patterns.
2. [Covariance and Contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/covariance-and-contravariance-faq)
3. And you also get to use Visual Studio 2010, which is much more flashy now.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 can be used with previous .NET frameworks.  Upgrading to Visual Studio 2010 does not require upgrading to .NET 4.0.

Comment: Yes, but you can't use 4 without it, so they come together.

Comment: no, VS2010 isn't included with .NET 4... it's a seperate product that costs $$$$$, the closest freebie is the Express editions which are definately decent for being free, but lack a ton of the $$$$ features

Comment: Not sure what is so complicated about this.  I agree.  I am trying to tell you you can't use .NET 4 without Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [big list of all the changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx), but for me:

1. Web.config minimization
2. Lazy
3. Web controls have cleaner markup
4. Covariance and Contravariance
5. VS 2010

Answer (score 0):

Support!!

If you take longer to upgrade you will end up having unfixed bugs in the future. Microsoft stops supporting older versions of their software after some time.

Comment: That's a valid reason to upgrade to VS2010--but not necessarily .NET 4.  Remember that VS2010 can target all versions of .NET from 2.0 onward.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework is a lot better in .NET 4. It supports directly accessing foreign keys, and  works as expected with Linq. In particular you can now use "Contains" with it, which makes things a lot easier.

The simpler WCF configuration is nice too.

Answer (score 0):

Great features are the awesome *Visual Studio 2010* and the *Entity Framework 4* (as already mentioned by Nix) as well as the new [Lazy<T> type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

A Better Debugger - I would kill someone for it back in VS2008 days.
When your solution is heavy and a weird hybrid of languages and technologies, debugger used to not work well.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/21/vs-2010-debugger-improvements-breakpoints-datatips-import-export.aspx

Comment: the debugger is not exclusive to .NET 4.  It's part of Visual Studio 2010, which can be used to develop .NET 2/3/3.5/4 apps

Comment: Ok, but you cannot develop against .Net 4.0 using VS2008 :)

Answer (score 0):

> ["... the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile is released as a recommended update that may be installed automatically on Windows Vista and Windows 7."](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982670)

This means you have to be less reliant on including binaries to include the .NET framework when you distribute your applications.

Comment: could you elaborate?  If you've previously had to ship core .NET assemblies (whether part of the client-profile, or the full framework) then you're implying your end-users didn't have .NET installed (or, perhaps, a 2.0 application was consuming 3.0/3.5 assemblies?!?)